# How to perform a click operation on an element which is a tuple?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element on a page which is a link and then click it. Here's a snapshot of the DOM: [image: Element DOM]

This is how I am trying to find it:

```
try:
    PublishAPostButton = WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance,30).until(lambda d:Driver.Instance.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='articles-actions']/a[starts-with(text(),'Publish a post')]")).is_displayed(), "Link still not exists"
except:
    print("Publish a post link not available")
else:
    PublishAPostButton.click()
    print("Publish a post link was clicked")
```

'Try' block executes without any error or exception BUT it returns a tuple (don't know why!). Control goes to 'else' and it tries to click. Obviously it cannot click a tuple and hence gives an error. Here's the error I get: **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'click'.** 
What I do not understand is how is it returning a tuple? Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Because your parentheses closing is not correct in the try block, change it to following:

```
try:
    PublishAPostButton = WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance,30).until(lambda d:Driver.Instance.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='articles-actions']/a[starts-with(text(),'Publish a post')]")).is_displayed()
except:
    print("Publish a post link not available")
else:
    PublishAPostButton.click()
    print("Publish a post link was clicked")
```

Comment: But the Try block will either return a True or a False. In the else block, click() operation cannot be performed on a bool value

Comment: No, the try block will assign the element to variable PublishAdPostButton